# WPF: ToolTip in New Window

Tags: c#, wpf, popup, tooltip

I have the following style for a ToolTip:

```
        <Style x:Key="ToolTipPopUp" TargetType="{x:Type ContentControl}">
            <Setter Property="Template">
                <Setter.Value>
                    <ControlTemplate TargetType="{x:Type ContentControl}">
                        <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal">
                            <StackPanel.ToolTip>
                                <ToolTip Visibility="Hidden" />
                            </StackPanel.ToolTip>
                            <ContentPresenter />
                            <Image Source="/Resources/info.png" 
                                   ToolTip="{TemplateBinding ToolTip}"
                                   Height="12"
                                   VerticalAlignment="Top" />
                        </StackPanel>
                    </ControlTemplate>
                </Setter.Value>
            </Setter>
        </Style>
```

This is called via:

```
            <ContentControl Style="{StaticResource ToolTipPopUp}" ToolTip="Hello world">
                <CheckBox Content="I am a check box" />
            </ContentControl>
```

This allows me to attach a `ToolTip` to any control I want and displays the `ToolTip` as expected.

[image]

The customer is now requesting that the `ToolTip` be shown in a pop-up window as the content can sometimes be rather lengthy.

Is there a way to convert this style to show a pop-up window?  I have read that a `Window` cannot be used by `ContentControl` so if there is a different way to do this I am open to that.

**EDIT**

I have a static resource of the instructions (not shown for clarity) that I bind to the ToolTip (that is what I am doing now).  I was thinking of creating a singleton window that would open when the user clicks on the tooltip icon (blue 'i'), would update a property in the pop-up window (i.e., the tooltip content) whenever a tooltip icon is clicked (so if the window is already open, the instructions within the window change).  The user can then close the window when they chose.

**SOLUTION**

Thanks to Theodosius for pointing me in the right direction.  Here is how I implemented this:

MainPageViewModel.cs (top-most window of executing program):

```
    private Window _toolTipWindow;

    /// <summary>
    /// Display the tool tip text in a new window
    /// </summary>
    public void ToolTipPopUpClicked(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        if (_toolTipWindow == null || !_toolTipWindow.IsVisible)
        {
            _toolTipWindow = new Window();
        }

        String _instructions = (((Button)sender).TemplatedParent as ContentControl).ToolTip.ToString();

        _toolTipWindow.Width = 300;
        _toolTipWindow.Height = 200;

        _toolTipWindow.Content = _instructions;
        _toolTipWindow.Show();
    }
```

**StylesDictionary.xaml**

```
<Style x:Key="ToolTipPopUp" TargetType="{x:Type ContentControl}">
    <Setter Property="Template">
        <Setter.Value>
            <ControlTemplate TargetType="{x:Type ContentControl}">
                <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal">
                    <ContentPresenter />
                    <Button Width="Auto">
                        <i:Interaction.Triggers>
                            <i:EventTrigger EventName="Click">
                                <ei:CallMethodAction TargetObject="{Binding RelativeSource={RelativeSource Mode=FindAncestor, AncestorType={x:Type Window}},
                                                                                        Path=DataContext}"
                                                             MethodName="ToolTipPopUpClicked" />
                            </i:EventTrigger>
                        </i:Interaction.Triggers>
                        <Button.Template>
                            <ControlTemplate>
                                <Image Source="Resources/info.png" 
                                            ToolTip="{TemplateBinding ToolTip}"
                                            Height="12"
                                            VerticalAlignment="Top" >

                                </Image>
                            </ControlTemplate>
                        </Button.Template>
                    </Button>
                </StackPanel>
            </ControlTemplate>
        </Setter.Value>
    </Setter>
</Style>
```

**XAML file**

```
            <ContentControl Name="PopupExample" 
                            Style="{StaticResource ToolTipPopUp}" 
                            ToolTip="Hello world">
                <CheckBox Content="I am a check box" />
            </ContentControl>
```

This retains the standard `ToolTip` functionality and provides a pop-up window when the user clicks on the tool tip icon (blue 'i').

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What about this then?

```
<Style x:Key="ToolTipPopUp" TargetType="{x:Type ContentControl}">
        <Setter Property="Template">
            <Setter.Value>
                <ControlTemplate TargetType="{x:Type ContentControl}">
                    <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal">
                        <StackPanel.ToolTip>
                            <ToolTip Visibility="Hidden" />
                        </StackPanel.ToolTip>
                        <ContentPresenter />
                        <Image Source="/info.png" 
                               ToolTip="{TemplateBinding ToolTip}"
                               Height="12"
                               VerticalAlignment="Top" >
                            <Image.Style>
                                <Style>
                                    <EventSetter Event="Mouse.MouseEnter" Handler="Show_PopupToolTip" />
                                    <EventSetter Event="Mouse.MouseLeave" Handler="Hide_PopupToolTip"/>
                                </Style>
                            </Image.Style>
                        </Image>
                    </StackPanel>
                </ControlTemplate>
            </Setter.Value>
        </Setter>
    </Style>
```

Code-behind...

```
Window win;

    private void Show_PopupToolTip(object sender, MouseEventArgs e)
    {
        var fred = ((Image)sender).TemplatedParent;

        if (fred != null)
        {
            ContentControl c = fred as ContentControl;
            string myText = c.ToolTip.ToString();

            if (!String.IsNullOrEmpty(myText))
            {
                if (win == null || !win.IsVisible)
                    win = new Window();
                win.Height = 275;
                win.Width = 275;
                win.Content = myText;
                win.Show();
            }
        }
    }
    private void Hide_PopupToolTip(object sender, MouseEventArgs e)
    {
        //if (win != null)
        //{
        //    win.Close();
        //}
    }
```

Comment: Please make your answer more useful by adding some content from your linked page, or a custom example on how to use a `Popup` control.

Comment: As far as I can tell the PopUp requires some method of handling the click event of a button associated with the PopUp.  I would prefer a solution that does not require a button & onClick event (and the associated code) as the original style is used in numerous UserControls.

Comment: Before i can give a better answer I need to know: What is the purpose for making it a window? Is it because the tooltip closes before they can read it all or what? A real window that would need to be closed would be so annoying! You can make the text in a tooltip wrap, if it is simply too long or something. See the my answer to see how you could make a custom tooltip popup.  This example still has you provide a ToolTip for the source of the text, you just disable the actual tooltip.  BTW, this code could be used to show any kind of control etc.

Comment: @TheodosiusVonRichthofen The customer wants the pop-up window to stay open and I think they plan on putting long instruction in the pop-up.  My reasoning for a window is that it could be moved as needed and then closed when desired.  One thing not in my OP is that there are a large number of these tool tips throughout the code so having the style made it very easy to implement over and over.

Comment: so are you planning on opening this window when the user clicks something, or is it just gonna open every time the mouse comes along?  that sounds terrible.  where are the "long instructions" going to come from, the tooltip property of the checkbox, or something else?

Comment: that should easily work with the code i provided you that adds the EventSetters and Handlers in the tooltip icon inside the style, doesn't sound like you need the one for MouseLeave